# Maximum Text Size For createBlockBlobFromText method Azure Storage, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

`createBlockBlobFromText(container: string, blob: string, text: string | Buffer, options: CreateBlobRequestOptions, callback: ErrorOrResult<BlobResult>)`

it is a method for writing text as block blob.

I want to know what is the limit of the text size.

In [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/understanding-block-blobs--append-blobs--and-page-blobs#about-block-blobs) it is said that "You create or modify a block blob by writing a set of blocks and committing them by their block IDs. Each block can be a different size, up to a maximum of 100 MB, and a block blob can include up to 50,000 blocks. The maximum size of a block blob is therefore slightly more than 4.75 TB (100 MB X 50,000 blocks"

Does this method saves as a single block meaning only 100MB? Or can I use more memory for the single blob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createBlockBlobFromText requires the size of text to be less than 64MB` got this error while trying to save a 200 mb text. So the limit is 64MB

To upload something more than 100MB we can to use `createWriteStreamToBlockBlob`

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable
var text = someWayTOGetText()
var s = new Readable
s.push(text)    
s.push(null)
s.pipe(blobService.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob('mycontainer', 'myblob.{format}',options));
```